# Creating unlimited subdomains that redirect to different IP's in PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, dns, subdomain

So iv'e been trying to find the right path for me for my situation but couldn't just find the right answer.
So what i need to do is a php script that will create a subdomain that redirects to an IP that will be sent from my post request.
Example - 
I post to script.php - ?username='test'&ip='127.0.0.1' 
I need this post request to create a subdomain with this username(the username will be used for the subdomain - test.mysite.com 
visiting test.mysite.com will redirect to 127.0.0.1 
What im trying to achive is something like a dns service. 
Is it possible? Do i need to ask my host for something(Godaddy/IIS Server) 
Thanks ! Really appreciate any lead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This requires 3 steps:

- You need to create a wildcard DNS entry for subdomains of your domain

> *.example.com A 192.0.0.10

- You then need to setup a new vhost entry for your apache server.  This should come after the vhost entry for your existing server, if it's running on the same machine as this subdomain redirection system.

> ```
> NameVirtualHost *:80
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>   DocumentRoot /var/www
>   ServerName www.example.com
>   ServerAlias *.example.com
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

- Finally, you write your index.php script to get `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` and based on that, to do a lookup in the database for your subdomain name, and send the header('Location:') based on a successful lookup in the database.

Comment: This assumes that you have a script, that stores the domains in a database.  You need something a table with a structure like id, domain, redirect.  The redirect can be an IP or hostname.   The *.example.com entry needs to point to YOUR publicly accessible server where your PHP script is going to run.